# Ubuntu: Authenticating against ldapjs server

Tags: ldap, ubuntu-14.04

Our developers have decided to go with ldapjs for a SSO solution for most of our applications. I have been tasked with getting our Ubuntu servers to authenticate against this ldapjs server. Although I know enough to get Ubuntu working with ldap to authenticate against an Active Directory server I am having issues getting this setup to work.

I have a bind user and the information for ou and o. I'm hoping that one of you generous individuals will be able to point me to some information that will help me further my project.

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: I'm having trouble setting up Ubuntu to authenticate against a ldapjs server. I've setup Ubuntu to authenticate against other versions of ldap except for this type. None of the information I know or have found point me in any direction that would help me to set it up.